# LED control using keyboard on Raspberry Pi 4 - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, keyboard, led

I am completely novice in Python and in Raspberry Pi. However, I have one, maybe easy to solve problem. I want to control LED diod on RPi4 with a keyboard.
If I press "1", I want the LED be active, and if I press "0" or any other key, I want to LED be inactive. I am running Python 3.7.3 on my Raspberry Pi4. The code below is working, but when I press "1" or "0", I have to run my code via command line again if I want to change status of LED.

Is there any solution, how to still read an input from keyboard and automatically based on it change the status of the LED?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(14,GPIO.OUT)

user_input = input("Input value 0 or 1: ")
print(user_input)

while (True):
    if user_input == "1":
        GPIO.output(14,GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        GPIO.output(14,GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only asking for the user input once. move the `input(...)` within the `while loop`.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(14,GPIO.OUT)

while True:
    user_input = input("Input value 0 or 1: ")
    print(user_input)

    if user_input == "1":
        GPIO.output(14,GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        GPIO.output(14,GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Suggestion: Since `while` is not a function call you should drop the parentheses and write `while True:`.